# Update CreatedBy(System.CreatedBy) workitem field in VSTS 2017

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We are unable to update CreatedBy(System.CreatedBy) workitem field in VSTS 2017 using rest API. The user has been added to "Project Collection Service Accounts" VSTS group in order to bypass the rules while updating the workitem.

Link: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs#L271

```
public WorkItem UpdateWorkItemUsingByPassRules(int id)
    {
        JsonPatchDocument patchDocument = new JsonPatchDocument();

        patchDocument.Add(
            new JsonPatchOperation() { 
                Operation = Operation.Add,
                Path = "/fields/System.CreatedBy",
                Value = "Foo <Foo@hotmail.com>"
            }
        );

        VssConnection connection = Context.Connection;
        WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

        WorkItem result = workItemTrackingClient.UpdateWorkItemAsync(patchDocument, id, null, true).Result;

        return result;
    }
```

When validateOnly parameter is set to true instead on null, then the result output holds the updated created by value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`System.CreatedBy` field can only be modified on work item creation.** If the work item has multiple revisions, `System.CreatedBy` can not be changed by bypassing rule.

You can also find it in [make an update bypassing rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#make-an-update-bypassing-rules):

> NOTE: System.CreatedBy and System.CreatedDate can only be modified
> using bypass rules on work item creation, i.e. the first revision of a
> work item.

Since `System.CreatedBy` and `System.CreatedDate` record who and when did a work item created, it can only be updated when you create the work item.